# PCL: Get the plane model from pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane / pcl::RandomSampleConsensus

Tags: point-cloud-library, ransac

How do you actually get the (a,b,c,d) plane model after doing ransac in PCL?

PCL: Get the plane model from pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane / pcl::RandomSampleConsensus

The examples only demonstrate how to extract the list of inliers.  I spent some time reading header files and the DOxygen reference, and coudn't figure it out.  Intuitively I would have expected RandomSampleConsensus to return a SampleConsensusModelPlane that would contain the plane parameters, but that class doesn't seem to contain ~any data members, let alone an obvious accessor for getting at them without unnecessarily recomputing anything.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

ugh.  I found it.

`pcl::RandomSampleConsensus` inherits `getModelCoefficients` from `pcl::SampleConsensus`.

Comment: Will close the question as soon SO lets me because it is embarrassing.